# Function to create accordion / collapsible trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, accordion

I have the following:

```html
<div class="Footer__Block Footer__Block--links">
  <h2 class="Footer__Title Heading u-h6">
</h2>
  <ul class="Linklist">
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I would like is that the "Footer__Title Heading u-h6" becomes a collapsible item (or an accordion) that can be clicked and the "Linklist" under it (with all the Linklist Items) opens up.

Could you please suggest a function for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `.toggle()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Footer__Title').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.Footer__Block').find('.Linklist').toggle()
  })
})

/* Vanilla version */
/*window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let footerTitle = document.querySelector('.Footer__Title')
  let linkList = document.querySelector('.Linklist')
  footerTitle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    linkList.classList.toggle('hidden')
  })
})
*/
```

```css
.Footer__Title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Footer__Block Footer__Block--links">
  <h2 class="Footer__Title Heading u-h6">The footer title
  </h2>
  <ul class="Linklist">
    <li class="Linklist__Item">
      Item
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! When I add the function, the links don't show up and stay hidden. Any ideas to what may be going on?

Comment: Yes, change this: `<ul class="Linklist hidden">` to this: `<ul class="Linklist">`

Comment: So the items reappear, but the toggle function isn't working

Comment: Is there a plunkr or something where I can see it? The snippet is working, so I'd have to see what we're talking about ...

Comment: Would you be able to convert the Jquery into plain Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: this is all vanilla js in my answer - do you mean the other way around (conver to jQuery)?

Comment: Excuse me, yes that is what I meant

Comment: One more thing: there are multiple "Footer__Block--links". So when one is clicked they all toggle. Would there be any way of toggling them in isolation?

Comment: thank you! last thing: i have now added a button (plus sign) next to the title. Upon clicking it I would like it to become a minus sign. Is there a function for this? I have tried CSS only but to no avail...

Comment: figure out which it needs to be, then: `$(this).closest('.Footer__Block').find('button').text('+') // or '-'`